# jquery delay multiple functions on initial load for slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am trying to get a slick effect with my slideshow that I am building for a client.

http://melvilledeli.com/demo/

I have 4 separate slideshows on a single page.

I want to have them cross fade transition one after the other. For example) instead of fading all at once, I want there to be a 5 seconds pause, then a slideshow 1 fades, then wait half a second, then slideshow 2 fades (top right), then wait half a second, slideshow 3 (bottom left) fades, and wait half a second and slideshow 4 fades (bottom right).

I can change the speed of the transitions but then after a while of watching the page the fades gets all jumbled up.

I want it to be like boom, boom, boom, boom.... wait 5 seconds then, boom boom boom boom.

I think that would look nice.

I tried using the .delay(500) and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I haven't tested it myself but, setting the sideshow period the same on each one, and then adding an increasing delay should do what you want.

```
        $('#slides').slides({
            effect: 'fade',
            crossfade: true,
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
            play: 6500,
            hoverPause: false
        }); 

        $('#slides2').delay(500).slides({
            effect: 'fade',
            crossfade: true,
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
            play: 6500,
            hoverPause: false
        });                 

        $('#slides3').delay(1000).slides({
            effect: 'fade',
            crossfade: true,
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
            play: 6500,
            hoverPause: false
        }); 

        $('#slides4').delay(1500).slides({
            effect: 'fade',
            crossfade: true,
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
            play: 6500,
            hoverPause: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make your 'play' param consistent for all slideshows. Then after you can you the 'play' and 'pause' methods like this:

```
$('#slides, #slides2').slides({
        effect: 'fade',
        crossfade: true,
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
        play: 6500,
        hoverPause: false
}); 

$('#slides2').slides('pause').delay(500).slides('play');
```

This isn't tested, but should work according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up in a flexible way using a timeout.  Just tweak the values and add to / remove from the slideshows array for as many slideshows as you need.

(Not tested but you should get the gist of the logic.)

```
//"constant" values
var MASTER_DELAY = 5000;
var STAGGER_DELAY = 500;

//Array of four Slideshow objects, DOM nodes ... or whatever they are in your case, and index for said array
var slideshows = [slideshow1, slideshow2, slideshow3, slideshow4];
var nextSlideshowIndex = 0;

var slideshowTimeout = setTimeout('onSlideshowTimeout()', MASTER_DELAY);

function onSlideshowTimeout()
{
  if(nextSlideshowIndex < slideshows.length)
  {
    $(slideshows[nextSlideshowIndex]).animate( /* ... slideshow animation code ... */ );
    slideshowTimeout = setTimeout('onSlideshowTimeout()', STAGGER_DELAY);
    nextSlideshowIndex++;
  }

  else
  {
    slideshowTimeout = setTimeout('onSlideshowTimeout()', MASTER_DELAY);
    nextSlideshowIndex = 0;
  }
}
```